# how to call activity from clicking list item

Tags: android

My code is mentioned below and don't know what is wrong with it. I have list view in Fragment and want to call activity on clicking list item.

```
public class fren_fragment extends Fragment {
    FrenListAdapter cAdapter;
    ListView cListView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        cAdapter = new FrenListAdapter(getActivity());
        cListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        cListView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
        cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cListView.setItemChecked(position,true);
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CompanyDetailActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: in place of `context` replace with `getActivity()`

Comment: Your question here is very unclear, can you edit it to describe your specific problem? It might help to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: make sure your `onItemClick` is working by write some logcat for check it

Comment: i dont know how to write it please can u give me the code?

Comment: Its probably just crashing in the `CompanyDetailActivity` so as far as this question goes it is solved 5 times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Context` for your `Intent` is wrong, try this.

```
cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        cListView.setItemChecked(position,true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
})
```

Comment: the app gets crashed after i click list items

Comment: can you tell me how to add this activity on android manifest.xml??? i havent added this activity on android manifest

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.nawin.demo/com.example.nawin.demo.CompanyDetailActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Well have you declared the activity in your manifest? `<activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.CompanyDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            cListView.setItemChecked(position, true);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyDetailActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
 Context context = view.getContext();
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, CompanyDetailActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyDetailActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i think i have done silly mistake in CompanyDetailActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_fragment, container, false);
cAdapter = new FrenListAdapter(getActivity());
cListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
cListView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        cListView.setItemChecked(position,true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyDetailActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

remove

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
```